# np_utils.to_categorical Reverse

Tags: python, numpy, keras

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils
nsample = 100
sample_space = ["HOME","DRAW","AWAY"]
array = np.random.choice(sample_space, nsample, )
uniques, coded_id = np.unique(array, return_inverse=True)
coded_array = np_utils.to_categorical(coded_id)
```

Example

Input

```
 ['AWAY', 'HOME', 'DRAW', 'AWAY', ...]
```

Output coded_array

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

How to reverse process and get the original data from coded_array?

Comment: Are you looking to get `ids` or `arr`? If `arr`, I think we need `uniques` too.

Comment: I'm looking for arr

Comment: So, do we have `uniques` as input to `decode()` too?

Comment: i can do so, with returning two elements at encodes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`np.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to retrieve back those `ids` and then simply indexing into `uniques` should give you the original array. Thus, we would have an implementation, like so -

```
uniques[y_code.argmax(1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [44]: arr
Out[44]: array([5, 7, 3, 2, 4, 3, 7])

In [45]: uniques, ids = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)

In [46]: y_code = np_utils.to_categorical(ids, len(uniques))

In [47]: uniques[y_code.argmax(1)]
Out[47]: array([5, 7, 3, 2, 4, 3, 7])
```

Comment: wt if my array is a str like [a,b,c,d,e]

Comment: @hks014 Where `a`, `b`, .. are strings or numerals or something else?

Comment: something like [cat,dog,bird,fish], after encoding ,it will be [[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0]]

Comment: @hks014 `np.argmax`. So, alternatively, you could do `uniques[np.argmax(y_code,1)]` or `np.take(uniques,np.argmax(y_code,1))`.

Comment: @hks014 What does it say?

Comment: @hks014 It's hard to read code in comments. Could you edit your question with sample inputs and those code?

Comment: I added some example

Comment: It doesn't work for me. But `np.argmax(y_code,1)` works fine (without `np.unique()`)

Comment: @Dmitry Post a new question explaining what you are expecting and how it doesn't.